# SharePoint 2013 - Publish provider hosted app - event receiver in an on-premises environment

Tags: apps-development

I have a functionality to add an app event receiver to host web list. When a new list item is created, the "ItemAdded" event need to be triggered in the host web list. I am developing this functionality with a app event receiver through SharePoint 2013 provider hosted app with App Installed event(property made to true) using Visual Studio 2013 in an on-premises environment. The functionality works fine when I click F5( debugging state).

I have tried both with self signed certificate and original CA certificate.

Now I need to package and publish my App Receiver. I am getting error in installation.

I am able to package and publish a sample provider hosted app to a site collection, but when the App receiver is enabled, the app installation throws error during adding to site.

Some blogs said to enable Anonymous authentication, so that app can call the receiver.svc , still it doesn't work.

Is there any proper documentation to package and publish App Receiver in SharePoint 2013 in on-premises environment?